# psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused - Same code works from one system but not from another

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I am trying to connect to redshift and the same code (same host, User, DB name, pwd, port) works from one computer but throws `connection refused` error from another one . Both the systems first connect to VPN and trying to connect to database.  Not sure if any of the config file needs to be updated with IP ? Not sure what could be the reason.

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is server running on host xxx.xx.xx.xx and accepting TCP/IP connections on port YYYY
```

Answer (score 0):

"Connection refused" means it couldn't even get ahold of the database to attempt to establish a connection with it.  Whatever is going on is happening at the networking level, not within the database.

Comment: Fixed this one. There was some issue with the VPN.